# Get country name and code of user

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to get user's country from the sim card and it should not be changed if he is in roaming i.e. If I have sim card of India and I am travelling to US then still I should get the country as India only not US.

So what should I use - getNetworkCountryIso() or getSimCountryIso().

I am really confused between two since I have read somewhere that getNetworkCountryIso() returns current country, that means it will be changed if I am in international roaming.

Answer (score 1):

**getSimCountryIso**

> getSimCountryIso depends on the operator to burn the country iso on the SIM and it also supports CDMA networks

**getNetworkCountryIso()**

> Returns the ISO country code equivalent of the current registered operator's MCC (Mobile Country Code).

for more information read [**TelephonyManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)